# ubuntu 16.04 に mac の I/O Kit（のヘッダファイル） をインストールする方法はあるでしょうか？

Tags: macos, go, ubuntu, usb

u2f USB機器(yubikey) を操作したく、
https://github.com/mdp/u2fcli
を、 ubuntu 16.04 上で
github + circle ci で golang buid (linux, windows, darwin)
の golang クロスコンパイルしようとしたのですが、mac(darwin)用コンパイルで、

```
$ export CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=gcc && gox --osarch "linux/amd64 darwin/amd64 windows/amd64" --output "dist/{{.Dir}}_{{.OS}}_{{.Arch}}"
Number of parallel builds: 3

-->   windows/amd64: _/home/xxx/github.com/sreinfrasystemjp/u2fcli
-->     linux/amd64: _/home/xxx/github.com/sreinfrasystemjp/u2fcli
-->    darwin/amd64: _/home/xxx/github.com/sreinfrasystemjp/u2fcli

--> darwin/amd64 error: exit status 2
Stderr: # net
could not determine kind of name for C.AI_MASK
# github.com/flynn/hid
../../../.go/src/github.com/flynn/hid/hid_darwin.go:6:36: fatal error: IOKit/hid/IOHIDManager.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

というエラーで、コンパイルできません。

ubuntu 16.04 に mac の I/O Kit（のヘッダファイル） をインストールする方法はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ヘッダファイルはテキストファイルなので、既にそれらのファイルを持っている場合は、単にコピーすれば良いだけです。
ただし実行ファイルを作るのに必要なのはヘッダファイルだけではないはずですし、たとえ出来たとしても動作確認をするためにMacのUSBポートが必要と思われるので、意味がないでしょう。

Mac/iOS用開発環境のXCodeをインストールしたいというならば、それは出来ません。
[Can you Run Xcode in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406151/can-you-run-xcode-in-linux)
[Can I install xcode in ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303013/can-i-install-xcode-in-ubuntu)
これはiPhone向け開発のガイドですが[［iPhone］Xcode をインストールする, iOSアプリ作成準備](https://i-app-tec.com/ios/xcode-install.html)

開発/動作確認用としてMacを買うか、Macを持っている人に頼むか、Mac向けプログラムは諦めるか、のどれかでしょう。

Comment: circle ci の有料オプション https://circleci.com/product/ なら、xcodeのコンパイル環境提供されているのですが、OSSにデイリービルドつけたいだけの為にその料金はねー、という所です。でも他の手段はなさそうですね...